# Combine two list of tuples depending on name

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have two lists of tuples:

```
a=[(name_2,array_2),(name_7,array_7),...,(name_n,array_n)]
b=[(name_3,arr_3),(name_12,arr_12),...,(name_n,arr_n)]
```

I want to combine them depending on their name which is the first value of each tuple in each set. The lists are not sorted by name. The result shall look like:

```
combined=[(name_1,array_1,arr_1),(name_2,array_2,arr_2),...,(name_n,array_n,arr_n)]
```

Is there any more effective solution than iterating with two pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sorted_a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0])
sorted_b = sorted(b, key=lambda x: x[0])

combined = [(sorted_a[idx][0], sorted_a[idx][1], sorted_b[idx][1]) for idx in range(len(a))]
```

Comment: Thank you for your approach, but I think your solution requires that my two lists are sorted by name, which is not the case. Sorry that I created these confusing examples. I will edit that. or is there an easy way to sort both list of tuples by the name they inherit.

Comment: yes, there is: `sorted_a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0])`. But if a and b have different lengths (or different set of names) just sorting them is not enough

Comment: no, they have the same length. It is always a pair of training and truth arrays.

Comment: @SergeantIdiot ok then, edited answer

Answer (score 1):

I assume the two lists have the same number of elements and the names are in the same order (by the way it looks from your example). In that case

```
[(x[0], x[1], y[1]) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're saying they are pairs, most of the answers here are perfectly fine you just need to sort on the first item in the tuple before joining them together.

```
[(x[0], x[1], y[1]) for x, y in zip(sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0]),
                                    sorted(b, key=lambda x: x[0]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution to avoid sorting is to pass through dictionaries:

```
names = [x[0] for x in a]
ad = dict(a)
bd = dict(b)
combined = list({k: [ad[k], bd[k]] for k in names}.items())
```

On my machine, with vectors `a` and `b` of size 1000, this takes 384 us against 667 us when sorting the two arrays. NB: The final `combined` list is not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

With `pandas`

```
list(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a).set_index(0) for x in (a , b)],axis=1).reset_index().itertuples(index=False,name=None))
[('name_1', 'array_1', 'array_1'), ('name_2', 'array_2', 'array_2')]
```